# Why Javascript doesn't check All checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a script which checks all the checkboxes when I click on the first one. It is working perfectly when I'm using onClick event in HTML, however it doesn't work, when I'm trying NOT to use the onClick Event.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<table>

<tr>
    <td><input id="check-all" type="checkbox"/>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input id="check1"  type="checkbox" name="check"/>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td ><input id="check2"  type="checkbox" name="check"/>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input id="check3"  type="checkbox" name="check"/>
</tr>
```

And this is the Javascript code I'm tring to run, but doesn't work.

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById("check-all");

checkbox.onclick = function () {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

I have just started out with Javascript, I might have did something wrong. Please point it out.

Comment: what is source.checked ? i think it should be checkbox.checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have an undefined variable:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById("check-all");

checkbox.onclick = function () {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = this.checked;
  }
}
```

You need to replace 'source' which isn't defined anywhere with a value to get the checked value of 'check-all', e.g. this.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Yes this was my fult. I didn't even recognize that "source". Thanks for the help buddy. :)

Comment: No worries. Tick this as answered if you're happy - will mark it so that people can see an answer is received on the main list.

Answer (score 0):

Your source.checked is invalid and wrong use

```
this.checked
```

instead of

```
source.checked
```